# recursion in rearranging related data

Tags: matlab, recursion

I have a struct, result like so:

> ```
> result.me={dad,grandpa,half_sis}
> result.step_mom={half_sis}
> result.dad={me,grandpa,half_sis}
> result.half_sis={mom,me,dad,grandpa}
> result.grandpa={me,dad,half_sis}
> ```

Result is a struct of cell arrays and shows the relatives(by blood) of each element. I wrote the following function, which takes the respective class_name(me,mom, etc) and it's respective cell and returns all of the relatives.
   For example, recur_getchildren(mom,{grandpa,me,sis},result) should return all the blood relative of mom AND all of those relative's relatives(and so on, until no one is left):

> ans=half_sis,me,dad,grandpa,

so even though mom is not related to me,dad or grandpa, they still get listed. The above example is a simplification, for my problem there will be many many more generations to keep track of. I tried to do the following, but it's not exactly working. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to do this?

```
 function tot=recur_getchildren(class_name,each_cell,result)
%gets all the children for an element and all its descendants
global gresult


if(~isfield(gresult,class_name))

    gresult.(class_name)=1;

    w=size(each_cell,2);
    tot=struct(char(class_name),1); %include the class_name item as well
    %tot is a struct where all the keys indicate the progeny, and val is 0/1

    for m=1:w


        %the child must not have already been searched previously
        if(~isfield(gresult,each_cell{m}))

            gresult.(char(each_cell{m}))=1;
            tot.(char(each_cell{m}))=1;
            % copy all contents over to parent
            if(sum(~strcmp(each_cell,'')) && sum(isfield(result,char(each_cell{m}))))
                s=size(result.(char(each_cell{m})),2);
                %run iteratively over all the children of each member of
                %each_cell
                for j=1:s

                    %struct of all childs
                    %gresult.(each_cell{m})=1;
                    if(~isfield(gresult,char(result.(char(each_cell{m})){j})))
                        tot.(char(result.(char(each_cell{m})){j}))=1;
                        % tot_records.(char(result.(char(each_cell{m})){j}))=1

                        tot2=recur_getchildren(each_cell{m},result.(char(each_cell{m}))(j),result);


                        %check off this so that we dont search it again
                        gresult.(char(result.(char(each_cell{m})){j}))=1;
                          %keep looping to get all children


                        %loop through result struct
                        if(size(tot2,2)~=0)
                            fn=fieldnames(tot2);
                            for p=1:size(fn)
                                str=fn(p);
                                recur_getchildren(char(str),result.(char(str)),result)
                                gresult.(char(str))=1;
                            end
                        end
                    end

                end
            end


        end
    end
else
    tot=[];
end
end
```

Comment: Are the names dad, grandpa, etc... strings?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done using some string evaluation and [set operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-42340.html#f16-7121).

If we have

```
result = 

      me: {'dad'  'grandpa'  'half_sis'}
      step_mom: {'half_sis'}
     dad: {'me'  'grandpa'  'half_sis'}
half_sis: {'mom'  'me'  'dad'  'grandpa'}
 grandpa: {'me'  'dad'  'half_sis'}
```

We can select one person and find that persons relatives.

```
s = result.step_mom

s = 

    'half_sis'
```

Using some string operations we can then find the relatives of the relatives like this:

```
eval(char(strcat('result.',s)))

ans = 

    'mom'    'me'    'dad'    'grandpa'
```

This gives us an idea for a function:

```
function children=recur_getchildren(result,person)

%Find all relatives of given person
s = eval(strcat('result.',person));

%Go through all relatives found in s
for i=1:size(s,2)
    children = union(s(i),eval(char(strcat('result.',s(i)))));
end

%remove orignal relative from other relatives
children=setdiff(children,person);
```

Lets test it:

```
relatives=recur_getchildren(result,'mom')

relatives = 

    'dad'    'grandpa'    'half_sis'    'me'
```

Note that you need to change step_mom into mom (or vice versa) for this to work in all cases.

EDIT: Just make it recursive. Something like this:

```
function [All_relatives,not_examined]=...
recur_getchildren(result,person,examined,All_relatives)


%Find all relatives of given person
s = eval(strcat('result.',person));

children = '';

%Go through all relatives found in s
for i=1:size(s,2)
    children = union(children,eval(char(strcat('result.',s(i)))));
end

%Save all found relatives
All_relatives = union(All_relatives,children);
All_relatives = union(All_relatives,s);

%Save all examined persons
examined = union(examined,s);
examined = union(examined,person);
not_examined = setdiff(All_relatives,examined);


count=0;
while length(not_examined)>0
    count=count+1;
    examined = union(examined,not_examined(count ));
    [new_relatives,not_examined] = recur_getchildren(result,char(not_examined(count)),examined,All_relatives);
    All_relatives = union(All_relatives,new_relatives);

end
```

This was just quickly put together, but should work. Give *examined* and *All_relatives* input as empty strings when running.

```
children=recur_getchildren(result,'me','','')
```

Comment: not sure if I'm seeing this correctly, but this code doesn't seem to accomodate getting a person's relative's relative's relatives and so on... It only seems to be getting the person's relative and those relative's relatives.